# db.SaveChange EntityValidationErrors Exception

Tags: c#, validation, exception

I have a problem with my program: I get my data from a database and I am trying to create a new personnel with a Button and add it to the list in the first column, but I am getting an exception.

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Here is my code:

```
private void neuespersonal_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        Personal p = new Personal();
        p.Vornameh4 = "Neues Personal";
        p.Nachnameq5 = "Nachname";
        Bestellungen b = new Bestellungen();
        b.Bestelldatumh8 = new DateTime(1982,05,21);


        p.Bestellungens.Add(b);



        db.Personals.Add(p);
        db.SaveChanges();  //i get the Exception here
        personal.Items.Refresh();


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap your code in a try catch and inspect the `EntityValidationErrors` property of the exception to know what is the causing the problem. It might be many thing (like a required field missing, a FK that isn't respected, etc...)

Comment: what do you mean exactly if i put it in the try section what do i have to write in the catch section?

Comment: If you catch the exception that is thrown, you can, while debugging, check the `Locals` tab for the exception and inspect the content. `try { /* your code */ } catch(DbEntityValidationException e) { /* breakpoint here and inspect the local variable e */ }`

Comment: `The thread '<No Name>' (0x177c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1490) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'BeispielWpf.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_de_31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.resources.dll'`    thats the error i get

Comment: ive solved the problem but it still doesnt add the personnel to the list but i get no exceptions now

Answer (score 0):

You will get this when you attempt to save an entity with data that does not validate against the model.  I would check the properties on the model accept the data you are trying to populate.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config. Perhaps you have some kind of error in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following mechanic to be useful.
Make sure you have the following:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
```

Within the function that commits the save:

```cs
    private void SaveDataFunction()
    {
        // entry input validation, rules check and the like
        // now the save this is an example for new record insert (LINQ)
        try
        {
            MyDBTable _rec = new MyDBTable;
            _rec.FieldName = "Some Value";
            db.MyDBTable.Add(_rec);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbx)
        {
             string _msg = "Record count not be saved.  The following validation errors occurred:";
             int _ctr = 1;
             foreach(DbEntityValidationResult _err in dbx.EntityValidationErrors)
             {
                  foreach(DbValidationError _thisErr in _err.ValidationErrors)
                  {
                       _msg = string.Format("{0}\nError: {1}. {2} on {3}", _msg, _ctr.ToString(),_thisErr.ErrorMessage, _thisErr.PropertyName);
                       _ctr++;
                   }
             }
             MessageBox.Show(_msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //optional or you could add other Exception types depending on circumstances
        {
            MessageBox.Show("record could not be saved. \n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Other things to consider is having an *Errors Container* class.  How you might use this as a place to hold the DbException and a container property to hold the failed items.  This allows the user to interact, correct and reattempt the save.
Just a thought.